# A general-purpose warp-level std::copy-like function - what should it account for?

Tags: optimization, cuda, gpgpu, stl-algorithm

A C++ standard library implements `std::copy` with the following code (ignoring all sorts of wrappers and concept checks etc) with the simple loop:

```
for (; __first != __last; ++__result, ++__first)
    *__result = *__first;
```

Now, suppose I want a general-purpose `std::copy`-like function for warps (not blocks; not grids) to use for collaboratively copying data from one place to another. Let's even assume for simplicity that the function takes pointers rather than an arbitrary iterator.

Of course, writing general-purpose code in CUDA is often a useless pursuit - since we might be sacrificing a lot of the benefit of using a GPU in the first place in favor of generality - so I'll allow myself some boolean/enum template parameters to possibly select between frequently-occurring cases, avoiding runtime checks. So the signature might be, say:

```
template <typename T, bool SomeOption, my_enum_t AnotherOption>
T* copy(
    T*        __restrict__  destination, 
    const T*  __restrict__  source,
    size_t                  length
);
```

but for each of these cases I'm aiming for optimal performance (or optimal expected performance given that we don't know what other warps are doing).

Which factors should I take into consideration when writing such a function? Or in other words: Which cases should I distinguish between in implementing this function?

**Notes:**

- This should target Compute Capabilities 3.0 or better (i.e. Kepler or newer micro-architectures)
- I don't want to make a Runtime API `memcpy()` call. At least, I don't think I do.

Comment: Doesn't this [already exist](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/group___util_io.html)?

Comment: @talonmies: I don't think so; those CUB functions/methods are for loading data into decomposed/spread-out/striped/etc. forms. And some of them are block-level. But it's a good place to go for inspiration I suppose.

Answer (score -2):

Factors I believe should be taken into consideration:

- **Coalescing memory writes** - ensuring that consecutive lanes in a warp write to consecutive memory locations (no gaps).
- **Type size vs Memory transaction size I** - if `sizeof(T)` is `sizeof(T)` is 1 or 2, and we have have each lane write a single element, the entire warp would write less than 128B, wasting some of the memory transaction. Instead, we should have each thread place 2 or 4 input elements in a register, and write that
- **Type size vs Memory transaction size II** - For type sizes such that lcm(4, `sizeof(T)`) > 4, it's not quite clear what to do. How well does the compiler/the GPU handle writes when each lane writes more than 4 bytes? I wonder.
- **Slack due to the reading of multiple elements at a time** - If each thread wishes to read 2 or 4 elements for each write, and write 4-byte integers - we might have 1 or 2 elements at the beginning and the end of the input which must be handled separately.
- **Slack due to input address mis-alignment** - The input is read in 32B transactions (under reasonable assumptions); we thus have to handle the first elements up to the multiple of 32B, and the last elements (after the last such multiple,) differently.
- **Slack due to output address mis-alignment** - The output is written in transactions of upto 128B (or is it just 32B?); we thus have to handle the first elements up to the multiple of this number, and the last elements (after the last such multiple,) differently.
- **Whether or not `T` is trivially-copy-constructible**. But let's assume that it is.

But it could be that I'm missing some considerations, or that some of the above are redundant.

Factors I've been wondering about:

- The block size (i.e. how many other warps are there)
- The compute capability (given that it's at least 3)
- Whether the source/target is in shared memory / constant memory
- Choice of caching mode